# Using Jest and React to test a component. Cannot read text element that is rendered on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, components, react-testing-library

I am not the most familiar with Jest, but have been struggling to test a component that renders text on the event of clicking a button. The text is taken from a random index of a mongodb collection (logic is in the backend) that is turned into a JSON file via mongoose. I get this error when trying to run the test.

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: About:. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="search"
    >
      <button
        type="submit"
      >
        Search
      </button>
      <div
        role="textbox"
      >
        <div />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

  14 |     console.log(text);
  15 |     // text should contain the word "About:" when rendered
> 16 |     expect(screen.getByText("About:")).toBeInTheDocument();
     |                   ^
  17 |   });
  18 | });
  19 |
```

```js
// useState is a hook, and we use curly braces to destructure it
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { isEmpty } from "lodash";

const ButtonSearch = () => {
  // this is the initial value
  const document = useRef();

  // this function fetches data from the backend, returns as a json file, and saves it to my document file
  const netflix = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/netflix")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => (document.current = data));
  };

  netflix();

  const [media, setMedia] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // the new value when clicked
    netflix();
    setMedia({
      title: document.current.title,
      type: document.current.type,
      releaseYear: document.current.release_year,
      rating: document.current.rating,
      duration: document.current.duration,
      description: document.current.description,
    });
    console.log(document.current);
  };

  let text = (
    <div>
      {!isEmpty(media) ? (
        <p>
          Your random result is: {media.title}
          <br />
          {media.title} is a {media.type} that came out in {media.releaseYear}.
          It is {media.rating} rated, and is {media.duration} long. <br />
          About: <i>{media.description}</i>
        </p>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
      <div role="textbox">{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ButtonSearch;
```

Here is my test document for it

```
import ButtonSearch from "../buttonSearch";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe("my test for ButtonSearch", () => {
  test("Check to see if text rendered on button click", async () => {
    render(<ButtonSearch />);
    const button = screen.getByRole("button");
    // Simulate clicking button
    await userEvent.click(button);
    const text = screen.getByRole("textbox");
    console.log(text);
    // text should contain the word "About:" when rendered
    expect(screen.getByText("About:")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have never seen any of the `window.current` pattern for `setState` and it looks like an antipattern. Your component is probably flakey by design. You can use `await screen.findByText()`, but it's still bound to give you false confidence.

Comment: Call `netflix` function in the component function directly is not correct.